# How make a query with Mongodb with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a object Post, with some attributes.And I want search there object by single attribute.In my example, it would be so

```
[58] pry(main)> Post.last
=> #<Post _id: 54e3852d776561352d020000, title: "123456", body: "4131231", draft: false, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('54e22da377656150d5000000')>
```

Need to find by 'draft' attribute.In postgres I would have done so

```
Post.where("draft = ?", false)
```

but how to do the same only Mongodb?

**upd**

```
[72] pry(main)> Post.where("draft = ?", false)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bundler/gems/mongoid-660868d73b36/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:416:in `where'
```

**2upd**

```
[2] pry(main)> Post.where(draft: false)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"draft"=>false}
  options:  {}
  class:    Post
  embedded: false>
```

Comment: `Post.where("draft = ?", false)` it is not working with Mongo ?

Comment: no, intepreter show an error. update the question

Comment: `Post.where(draft: false).first` <~~ what is it giving ?

Comment: Try this and let us know what is shows : Post.where(draft: false).map(&:title)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Post.where(draft: false).each { |rec| puts rec.title }
# or you can write
Post.where("this.draft == false").each do |rec|
  puts rec.title
end
```

Note: [`#where`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#where-instance_method) will give you [`Mongoid::Criteria`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria) object not the actual records. You have to iterate through this object using `#each`, [`#first`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Findable#first-instance_method) to get the first record etc.

Comment: @vveare138 It should work --- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#where-instance_method

Comment: it does not work.Look, I do like this: post = Post.where("this.draft == false") and after I call this variable 'post.title' and irb show an error 'NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000006892668>'

Comment: Can you post the response of just Post.where(draft: false) here ?

Comment: @vveare138 Did you try.. what I said ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in irb and see if the titles are showing :

```
Post.where(draft: false).map(&:title)
```